# C#: Get the name of a property and check its value

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following class Franchise:

```
public class Franchise 
        {
            public string FolderName { get; set; }
            public string InstallerExeName { get; set; }
        }
```

I have a method that checks specific property value for uniqness among all franchises in the db.

```
public bool ValidateFolderName(string folderName)
        {
            var allFranchises = _franchiseService.GetAll();
            var result = allFranchises.Any(f => f.FolderName == folderName);
            return result;
        }
```

The problem is I have to check another property for uniqness:

```
public bool ValidateInstallerExeName(string installerExeName)
        {
            var allFranchises = _franchiseService.GetAll();
            var result = allFranchises.Any(f => f.InstallerExeName == installerExeName);
            return result;
        }
```

I want to avoid code duplication by making a generic method. Something like:

```
public bool ValidateProperty(string propertyName)
        {
            var allFranchises = _franchiseService.GetAll();
            // Not sure how to write this line
            var result = allFranchises.Any(f => f.[propertyName] == propertyName);
            return result;
        }
```

The problem is I am not sure how to re-write this line of code so that it can get the property name and check its value by the provided parameter:

```
 var result = allFranchises.Any(f => f.[propertyName] == propertyName);
```

I know I can do something like this with reflection:

`franchise.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(franchise, null);`

but I am not sure how can I make this to fit my case. Any help with working example will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full working example using reflection:

```
class Program
{
    private static List<Franchise> allFranchises;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        allFranchises = new List<Franchise>
        {
            new Franchise() { FolderName=@"c:\1", InstallerExeName="1.exe" },
            new Franchise() { FolderName=@"c:\2", InstallerExeName="2.exe" },
            new Franchise() { FolderName=@"c:\3", InstallerExeName="3.exe" },
            new Franchise() { FolderName=@"c:\4", InstallerExeName="4.exe" },
            new Franchise() { FolderName=@"c:\5", InstallerExeName="5.exe" },
        };

        Console.WriteLine(ValidateProperty("FolderName", @"c:\2", allFranchises));
        Console.WriteLine(ValidateProperty("InstallerExeName", "5.exe", allFranchises));
        Console.WriteLine(ValidateProperty("FolderName", @"c:\7", allFranchises));
        Console.WriteLine(ValidateProperty("InstallerExeName", "12.exe", allFranchises));
    }

    public static bool ValidateProperty(string propertyName, object propertyValue, IEnumerable<Franchise> validateAgainst)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(Franchise).GetProperty(propertyName);
        return validateAgainst.Any(f => propertyInfo.GetValue(f, null) == propertyValue);
    }
}

public class Franchise
{
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    public string InstallerExeName { get; set; }
}
```

It will print out:

```
True
True
False
False
```

as expected.

Comment: Thank You for your answer! I tried your example, but it only works in .net 4.5 version of the framework. It seems that 'propertyInfo.GetValue(f)' does not take the same parameters in 4.0 (which I am using).

Comment: @Mdb Yes, seems that 4.0 is missing this single parameter overload. I modified the example and it now works with 4.0.

Comment: Yes, I looked through the documentation and fixed that. Thank You again!

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool ValidateProperty<TType, TPropertyType>(Func<TType, TPropertyType> propertySelector, TPropertyType propertyValue)
{
    return _franchiseService.GetAll().Any(f => propertySelector(f) == propertyValue);
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
if( ValidateProperty(x => x.FirstName, "Joe") )
```

This does not use reflection and you have intellisense for your propertyname as well.

Comment: And it has the added benefit of being usable in an O/RM to execute on the server rather than downloading the whole table and doing the check on the client (provided you are actually reading it from a database somewhere). You'll just have to use `Expression<Func<TType, TPropertyType>>` and it can be used inside `IQueryable.Any`, for example. Of course, it's also almost useless, since you're not eliminating duplication, you're adding it. Do you really feel that `ValidateProperty(x => x.PropertyName, val);` is simpler than `service.Any(x => x.PropertyName == val);`?

Answer (score 0):

You may use an extension method:

```
public static bool ValidateProperty(
    this IEnumerable<Franchise> franchises,
    string property,
    object value)
{
    var prop = typeof(Franchise).GetProperty(property);
    if (prop == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Property does not exist");
    return franchises.Any(f =>
        prop.GetValue(f) == value);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var r = _franchiseService.GetAll().ValidateProperty("FolderName", "myfolder1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the function you want using `System.Linq.Expressions`

```
public class Franchise 
{
   public string FolderName { get; set; }
   public string InstallerExeName { get; set; }

   bool ValidateProperty(string propertyName) {
     var allFranchises = new List<Franchise>();
     var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Franchise));
     var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
     var thisExpression = Expression.Constant(this, typeof(Franchise));
     var value = Expression.Property(thisExpression, propertyName);
     var notThis = Expression.ReferenceNotEqual(thisExpression, property);
     var equal = Expression.Equal(value, property);
     var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Franchise, bool>>(Expression.And(notThis, equal));


     // lamda is now the equivalent of:
     // x => !object.ReferenceEquals(this, x) && object.Equals(x.Property, this.Property)     
     return allFranchises.Any(lambda.Compile());
   }
}
```

If allFranchises is of type IQueryable you use `allFranchises.Any(lambda)`

You could also caches the expression for later use if you are worried about performance.
    }